# Is it possible to show file name in document version history

Tags: 2010, document-library, version-history

I am wondering if it is possible to track file name changes in SharePoint 2010 document version history?
Like when you change a property the document version will show that that value was changed. but i just realized that if a user does a file name change, it is not shown in the version history.

Comment: Because for all intents and purposes, a file name change constitutes a new document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

As Eric Alexander mentioned, renaming a document means recreating it (I wish it didn't!).
Proof: in order to rename a file you need the "Delete" privilege. SP probably does something nasty there...